# Feature manipulation for classification model

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm hoping to gain some advice in dealing with a classification model.

Let's say I have three outcome labels [low, medium, high] and three features [F1, F2, F3]. To keep it simple, let's say the features are a raw count within a fixed area. An increase in the nominal values in each feature is likely to predict a ‘high’ outcome for a particular event.

The central query is when factors may influence the features. Let's say 5-10% of the time the fixed area isn't adequate. Specifically, the whole area isn't operational, so a lower count may be considered 'high' because a smaller portion of space is active.

I'm reluctant to *manipulate* the features when these instances occur. But if I had a separate feature to consider it may not influence the rules because it occurs infrequently.

If this is confusing I can add some dummy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option would be to **add a separate feature** indicating the percentage of the total area that is operational. If this isn't available, at least add an indicator (i.e. 0-1) that shows if the full area is operational or not.

This way you are giving the model all available information. Internally the model can manipulate the features in any way it sees fit, in order achieve the best performance.

By manipulating the features on your own, you would essentially place your own assumptions on the data, which might not stand in practice.